# Purpose of floating points in Ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point

What is the purpose of a floating number in Ruby? I found some information about using less bytes or increasing accuracy, but I do not understand why you would not always use floats. Wouldn't it give you a more accurate result?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Oh, don't close it, although not the ideal SO question, it seems OK. After all, most or all Javascript implementations *do* use only FP numerics. For that reason alone it seems like a fair enough question about programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past, integer ops were much faster and sometimes the FPU was not present or was optional in the architecture.

However, today, FP is almost universal, it's quite fast, and in fact it *is* possible to use FP for everything.

Most or all Javascript implementations work like that.

In general, though, the integer ops are still faster and the catalog of available operations matches more closely to what programmers will expect. 64-bit integers map better to bytes and the storage system than the 52-bit integers provided by the floating point system.

A full-featured language like Ruby will almost always implement both integer and FP ops. It gives the user more of a choice for attribute domains, while languages that are more streamlined like Javascript may pick one or the other. Ruby is much more likely to need something like ORM than Javascript is.

Note, however, that the reason is not *"more accuracy".*  FP and integer operations return the exact same results for integer operands. FP has 52 bits, and although that's greater than the standard 32-bit *int* it's less than the also-common 64-bit long or long long, so no one really wins or loses on precision. Both are accurate.

And yes, as Jörg hints, the integer ops are more easily extended to greater precision.

Comment: It's not true that floats are as accurate as integers. Floats can only accurately represent integers up to 10 quadrillion, whereas integers can represent *all* integers, provided there is enough memory.

Comment: @Jörg, well, that's true of the Ruby *Integer* class, but Lili never mentioned that. It seemed reasonable to interpret the question along the lines of *why do we use the scalar operations* and ignore the software-extended-range types. After all, Ruby *could* have implemented extended floats, or even used a hybrid approach with extended scaler ops. I rather doubt if Lili was talking about the non-*Fixnum* integers.

Comment: The question is tagged `[ruby]`. If it's not about Ruby, then why tag it as such?

Answer (score 0):

Integers are typically faster for some operations, and sometimes you want the chopping that results from integer division

Comment: Well, Jörg W Mittag said in a comment on DigitalRoss' answer that integers can represent all integers (he must be referring to a multi-precision integer type that may be the default in Ruby). If that's the case, then integers are not obviously faster than floating-point. 2^128 + 2^128 is slower as an integer computation, let alone 2^256  + 2^256. In fact, even single-word 64-bit integer multiplication can be slower than floating-point double-precision multiplication.